# microsoft graph subscription service forbiden

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using rest api to create subscription for calendar resources but getting below error. Can anyone help me out over here.

===========================================================

```
{
"error": {
"code": "ExtensionError",
"message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: ServiceUnavailable; Reason: Target resource '00030000-3c24-324c-0000-000000000000' hosted on database '1a65164a-54a2-469a-a1f2-a837508bb8a6' is currently on backend 'Unknown']",
"innerError": {
"date": "2021-07-03T21:19:13",
"request-id": "1259c1ae-42eb-4999-88a2-3fa8157f7816",
"client-request-id": "1259c1ae-42eb-4999-88a2-3fa8157f7816"
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is the Graph Endpoint you called? Also share the request body specifically the resource path you are subscribing to. How persistent is the issue?

Comment: POST /v1.0/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
HOST: graph.microsoft.com
content-type: application/json
authorization: Bearer <access token>
content-length: 437

{
  "notificationUrl":https://<domainname>/calendar/outlookCalendar/notifications, 
  "expirationDateTime":"2021-07-06", 
  "notificationContentType":"application/json", 
  "resource":"/me/calendars/<calendarid>/events", 
  "changeType":"created,updated",
  "latestSupportedTlsVersion":"v1_2"
}

Comment: Everything was working earlier but i noticed this since last 2-3 days. I am not sure if it is because of domain verification which i did on account level otherwise nothing changed on code level.

Comment: @GauravTripathi any update on this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: @abatis same, did you figure it out?